# How to find the center of mass for a system of multiple solid spheres?

Tags: mathematical-physics, spheres, centroid

Assuming spheres have continuous and uniform mass distribution ($\rho$). How can we compute the center of mass (`com`), e.g. for a system with 3 solid spheres: $(x_1, y_1, z_1, R_1)$, $(x_2, y_2, z_2, R_2)$, $(x_3, y_3, z_3, R_3)$ mathematically?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let calculate the mass of each sphere

$$M_i=\frac43 \pi \rho R_i^3$$

and then

$$x_C=\frac{\sum x_iM_i}{\sum M_i} \quad y_C=\frac{\sum y_iM_i}{\sum M_i} \quad z_C=\frac{\sum z_iM_i}{\sum M_i}$$

Note that since the mass is uniform we can substitute $M_i$ with $V_i$.

**EDIT**

In integral form, for the x component we have

$$x_C=\frac{\int\int\int_V x\,dm}{\int\int\int_V \,dm}=\frac{\int\int\int_{V_1} x\,dm+\int\int\int_{V_2} x\,dm+\int\int\int_{V_3} x\,dm}{\sum M_i}$$

note also that

$$\int\int\int_{V_i} x\,dm=x_i M_i$$

thus

$$x_C=\frac{x_1M_1+x_2M_2+x_3M3}{\sum M_i}=\frac{\sum x_iM_i}{\sum M_i}$$

Comment: Can you prove this? as if spheres are treated as point mass at the sphere center

Comment: It is a direct consequence of the additive properties by the definition. You can write down one sum and then divide into three different pieces.

Comment: @KOF is it clear or you need more details?

Comment: I mean, can you deduce these equations using integration form?

Comment: @KOF yes of course, you should also find it i any good physic book

Comment: I know how to compute inertia, center of mass of a point mass system. But for solid spheres...

Comment: @KOF you can write in integral form and for symmetry you easily find that the center of mass coincide with the center of the sphere (for uniform density).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72357/discussion-between-kof-and-gimusi).

Comment: @KOF I've added an integral derivation